# BeautifulSoup: get data in class that change name

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape an html page where the information I need are stored in a code like this:

```
<a class=" l00_PR_lTitleonContext" href="site0.html"> Title 0 </a>
<a class=" l01_PR_lTitleonContext" href="site1.html"> Title 1 </a>
<a class=" l02_PR_lTitleonContext" href="site2.html"> Title 2 </a>
[...]
```

I'd like to get "Title 0", "Title 1" and "Title 2" but the class name change for each item, so I'm using regex like this:

```
titles = soup.findAll("a", attrs={"class": re.compile('^TitleonContext.*')})


for title in titles:
   print(title)
```

But it's not working (nothing is printed). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following regex instead `re.compile(r'.*TitleonContext')` or `re.compile('.*TitleonContext')`, otherwise you're looking for this value to be started with (`^`).